# Strange GetLastError return in Managed C++

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, getlasterror

I have a really strange problem with GetLastError and managed C++. GetLastError is returning something very strange after transitioning from unmanaged code to managed code.

The error code: 122 - The data area passed to a system call is too small.

Additionally, the passed in strMessage is making it to the server.

**Unmanaged function:**

```
   DWORD SendMessage(LPCTSTR strMessage, CString * strResponse)
   {

     DWORD dwLastError;
     BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
     try 
     {
          //some socket code
          int ret =  recv...
          if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR || ret == 0)
          {
                Log(GetLastError());  //falls into here
                Log(WSAGetLastError());
                throw "Failed!"
          }
          bSuccess = TRUE;
     }
     catch (LPCTSTR pszException)
     {
         dwLastError = GetLastError();
         Log(pszException);
         Log(dwLastError );
         Log(WSAGetLastError());
     }

     Log(dwLastError);
     SetLastError(dwLastError);
     return bSuccess;
   }
```

**Managed Code:**

```
  void SendManagedMessage(String ^ strMessage)
  {
    CString cstrMessage = (char*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(strMessage).ToPointer();
    CString cstrResponse;
       if (!SendMessage(cstrMessage, &cstrResponse))
       {
           Log("Failed to send managed message");
           Log(GetLastError());
       }

       //...
  }
```

**Log output**

```
0
0
Failed!
Failed!
0
0
0
Failed to send managed message
122
```

Comment: Post the code that calls `recv()`.

Comment: You have a bug in your unmanaged code -- using unitialized variable dwLastError.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many functions will call `SetLastError` as a side-effect while doing their work.  Typically this means that a function calls some other function, which might have some internal failure for which it might call `SetLastError`, and so the previous error value is overwritten.

As an example, it's quite likely that something called by the `Log` function calls something that sets the `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`, handles that error, and returns success.  Result?  Even though your code didn't fail in a larger sense, your error value is clobbered.

When Win32 functions fail, you need to take some care to call `GetLastError` before calling too much unrelated code.

**Update:** I would also read the link in the comment.  Also, reading your code, where it says "Failed" followed by 0 error codes, I think likely what is happening is the other end closed the socket (i.e. `recv` returned 0).

Comment: It also looks like you can't call GetLastError from managed C++ reliably: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam_nathan/archive/2003/04/25/56643.aspx

Comment: @AdamDriscoll - +1.  I don't have any experience attempting to do this so I was not aware of such issues, but I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try adding:

```
dwLastError = 0;
```

For the success case. The way you have it, you can be calling SetLastError with an uninitialized variable. I am surprised you are not getting a compiler warning.